# What is the name of this fragrant and edible plant?

Tags: identification

[image]

It has a fragrance and it's also edible, I suspect it could be Mentha Longifolia, but I'm not sure. I try to propagate it through placing it in a cup filled with water near the window in order to get the sunlight that encourages the growth of roots. In a matter of 4 days the roots started to grow.

Comment: Where did you find it? Whats the smell?

Comment: @Jeremy It was given to me, the smell is like oregano and mint, same for the taste by the way.

Comment: It doesn't look like Mentha longifolia to me - leaves are often shorter, or a greyish green colour, and although I can see the underside on one leaf, its hasn't got that typical mint appearance - lots or ribs and a slightly velvety look. Not sure what it is though, not sure I'd eat it without ID - many herbs are more medicinal than culinary. Any idea what the flowers are like?

Comment: I have no idea about the flowers, but I ate some leaves and I'm completely fine.

Comment: Well whatever it is, it's definitely labitae so it's not going to hurt you, but I wouldn't eat any more of without knowing for sure what it is.

Comment: Let's wait until it flowers.

Comment: Hi direprobs! Did this flower yet? It may be too soon, but if it has, would you post some pictures, or a description of the flower? Thanks!

Comment: @Escoce *lamiaceae* doesn't mean "the safe plants" in Latin. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentha_pulegium .

Comment: @Escoce I did flower in fact, but I didn't take a photo for the plant with the flowers. In fact, the flowers are purple with white and are very small.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like **estragon** or **tarragon**; [*artemisia dracunculus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarragon). I cannot comment, therefore I risk it and give it as an answer